"No errors found by the IDE" in problems tab
My PyCharm always shows:

"No errors found by the IDE"


I don't open power save mode.

I don't know why. I even reinstalled PyCharm and shut down all plugins, however, my idea doesn't work well. I have search this problem on the internet but without finding any solution.

The problems tool window (Alt+6) you're showing often isn't used. Most developers just click on the red underline and see whatever error/suggestion the IDE's linter gives them right there. You can configure what's shown in the problems tab by going to File > Settings > Editor > Inspections click on the top list items for Python and Django sections and check the "scope" is set to your project and files.

Make sure you have the inspections activated.

Thank you for your answer! The reason I wanted to use this feature is that I have just made some major changes to the structure of my code, which has led to a lot of problems with "import" in many python files, and I have been using the problems tool to manually fix them one by one, as usual, but it keeps showing me "No errors found by the IDE". I used this problems tool as usual to solve them manually one by one, but it kept showing "No errors found by the IDE". This makes me confused.

Very likely a problem with the inspections scopes, I haven't had this problem and it might be Django specific but check the link in my second comment - the "scope" field when you click on the top Django item. Also see the warning in the inspections page that says "Disable new inspections by default" that might just be it because you're using a plugin...

It's also possible that you're in reader mode make sure you're in the normal editor mode.

Using the problems tool window doesn't work well because the IDE inspections/linter has common bugs, so if you're working on a large project you'll end up using 3rd party tools for most inspections and if you're refactoring you'll use the search&replace or "Find usages" (Alt+7)  because they're more efficient.
